# Getting Started with DataTables

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I'm trying to get DataTables implemented on  website form. I was experiencing some difficulties with that so I took a step back and tried to implement DataTables on a very basic table. The table I used came straight off of http://www.datatables.net/usage/. I then called in files I thought were needed but I'm still failing to get Datatables to work on even this basic of a table. What am I missing? Here's the "practice" code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/media/src/DataTables.js"></script>-->

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table').dataTable();
    } );
    </script> 
    <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
        @import "/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css";
    </style>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>


    <table id="table" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>etc</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
            <td>etc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
            <td>etc</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: are your .js files getting loaded? Are you seeing any errors in your console?

Comment: Checkout the path of js files, if your htm exists in the same root folder of the downloaded example...jquery and datatables script src should be "media/js/jquery.js" i.e., without "/" in the start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are the js and css files actually being loaded? You can debug that with firebug on firefox or in development tools in webkit browser. (just right click in the table and select "Inspect Element")

Also, DataTables [is available on the Microsoft Ajax CDN](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#jQuery_DataTables_Releases_on_the_CDN_6). Same as j[Query](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js)

You can try to use the external link and see if it works. like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Also note that using external libraries is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether jQuery is loaded first. Then check whether dataTables assets are working. you can check that with an alert function 
Instead of using @import within your internal stylesheet, prefer using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="filepath/style.css">
```

In my [blog](http://creativetechnocrayts.blogspot.in/2018/03/datatables-options-in-this-article-we.html), you can see steps and other options to use Datatables.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add one attribut : " defer " to the script.

```
<script src = "http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" defer ></script>
```