# Adding DataTables plugin to Groovy Grails Tool Suite

Tags: grails, datatables, add-on

I am trying to add [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net) to my Groovy/Grails project in order to clean up my tables and to add extra functionality.

I currently am having problems getting it to even work. I added the download folder to my project plugin folder but when I try to add the functionality to my project it doesn't seem to work, starting with just the cookey cutter example shown [here](http://www.datatables.net/blog/Getting_started_with_DataTables%3a_First_steps). 
Since that's not working I must have a problem with how I added the add-on to my files. I thought it was as easy as just taking the download file and moving it to the project plugin folder but that doesn't seem to be working.

Any advice on how to actually add the files to the project? They show up in my project directory in groovy grails but they show up at `doc.media`. Where they show how to include the `js` and `css` to the `html` page it shows datatable/media... I am not sure if this is a path error or what not. I have never actually added an add-on to this tool suite before. It was always given to me.

If someone could give me a decent rundown on how to actually add things like this I would greatly appreciate it.

This is my show.gsp

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
@import "/DataTables/media/css/demo_table.css";
</style>
<g:set var="entityName"
    value="${message(code: 'User.label', default: 'User')}" />
<meta name="layout" content="main">
<g:set var="entityName"
    value="${message(code: 'User.label', default: 'User')}" />
<title><g:message code="default.show.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#table_id').dataTable();
    });
</script>


</head>
    <body>
    <table id="table_id" class ="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
                <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
                <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This is my main.gsp

```
<!doctype html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
            <title><g:layoutTitle default="Grails"/></title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'favicon.ico')}" type="image/x-icon">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'apple-touch-icon.png')}">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'apple-touch-icon-retina.png')}">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'main.css')}" type="text/css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'mobile.css')}" type="text/css">
            <g:layoutHead/>
            <r:layoutResources />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div style ="font-weight:bold; font-size:20px" id="grailsLogo" role="banner"><a href="${createLink(uri: '/')}">Grails</a></div>
            <g:layoutBody/>
            <div class="footer" role="contentinfo"></div>
            <div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;"><g:message code="spinner.alt" default="Loading&hellip;"/></div>
            <g:javascript library="application"/>
            <r:layoutResources />
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the term "plugin" is throwing you.  This is not a Grails plugin - it is a jQuery plugin.  Totally different.  First of all make sure you have jQuery itself installed, active and working.

Your downloaded files will go in the following locations:

1. .js files in `web-app/js`
2. .css files in `web-app/css`
3. image files in `web-app/images` (I'm pretty sure this is where they will work based on looking at the css file)

Then to include them in a gsp page:

In `conf/ApplicationResources.groovy`

```
modules = {
    application {
        resource url:'js/application.js'
        resource url:'js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'
    }
}
```

In GSP

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir:'css', file: 'demo_table.css')}" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<g:set var="entityName"
value="${message(code: 'User.label', default: 'User')}" />
<meta name="layout" content="main">
<g:set var="entityName"
  value="${message(code: 'User.label', default: 'User')}" />
<title><g:message code="default.show.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('I am working'); //remove once you see the alert
    $('#table_id').dataTable();
});
</script>
</head>
....
```

(this should give you an alert when the page is loaded, just as a check to make sure jQuery is working.  After you see the alert once you can remove that `alert` line)

I included jQuery the way I use it; gets it from a CDN so I can keep up to date.

And then follow the rest of the example on the demo page you listed.

Comment: I was thinking going this route and became confused with the fact it is a "pluggin" Been trying to jump through hoops with groovy grails pluggin manager and installer and its been a pain! I will try this route and get back to you. Thanks for the response!

Comment: I get a HTTP Status 500. Error applying layout : main. Which is coming from <meta name="layout" content="main"> in my head. Which gives me my styling which was default from grails. When i remove that line everything goes black and white  but the datatables still does now work

Comment: Can you update the question to include your `main.gsp` layout and the head section from your other gsp?  And I'm a little confused on the wording - with no main layout included do the datatables work?

Comment: Here is my update. The main.gsp was just the stock one that grails made for me. Thanks for all the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: First try adding the CSS and javascript imports and testing jQuery to make sure it is installed and working.  I'll update my answer to show this.

Comment: Sorry took me awhile to get back. I still get the 500 error that I got before

Comment: OK I do get the alert when I use firefox, but it just shows a unformated table on a white page. And it only works when I take out the meta line

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733133/getting-started-with-datatables this got it to format. But the pagination doesnt work and it gives me a error every time it loads that page.

Comment: OK, I just played around with this a little more and I could reproduce that error.  It appears that the Resources plugin does not like the javascript set in the gsp.  Weird.  I'll update my answer to exactly what I did to get it to work, formatting, pagination and all.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I was able to get the basic table going but now I cant get it to work with my real table. But I think I can take it from here. I really appreciate your time and help!